# jQuery Mobile - Remove blanks in nested collapsiblesets

Tags: jquery, nested, padding

I have a collapsibleset with nested collapsiblesets. Like this:

(Couldn't post an image), here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uetmbsjl7wxjvu1/collapsible-set.PNG?dl=0).

I want to remove the white blank spaces that appear before and after the nested collapsibleset. I looked and tried something like this:

```
.ui-collapsibleset {
margin : 8px -15px;
}
```

And tried to set padding to zero on parent collapsible, and in nested collapsibleset, but nothing removes those. I have also tried with some code that works for listviews, but didn't work either.

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" id="popupCollapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-  theme="c" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" style="margin:0; width:400px;">

<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h1>a a</h1>
  <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" style="margin:0;">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h1>P</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
      <h1>Súper</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class (e.g. `noSpacing`) to the outer collapsibleset and try this:

```
.noSpacing > .ui-collapsible-content
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.noSpacing > .ui-collapsible-content > .ui-collapsible-set
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rosberglinhares/mnpbuL1v/).

Comment: It worked really well. Thank you! The last 5 days I was trying and trying. Very clear CSS. Thanks again!